# Should I report my GPA on applications for an MA if it is not required?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gpa

I am applying to a Master's program using an online application where I must report my prior university education. The field to report my undergraduate GPA is not required and would anyways be verified by using my transcripts before admission. It would, however, be more convenient for the application committee to get a feel for my undergraduate record if I were to report it voluntarily since they would not have to immediately match my application with my transcript. It should be noted that other materials (like a statement of purpose) are separate documents.

How will reporting or not reporting affect my chances of admission? Are they more likely to reject an application where they can immediately see a lower GPA, or one where they are unsure of what it is at first? I feel that my GPA may be a potential weakness in my application and would prefer not to have it advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it is better than average, volunteer it (if there is a convenient free text field).  If average or worse than average, don't volunteer it.

Comment: "Average" is difficult to measure. Remember that the average GPA of the MS applicant pool is almost certainly higher than the average GPA of an undergraduate program. Competition can be stiff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that they have thought it all out. There is probably a clerical service that puts things together for the committee before they even look at it.

Report what is needed but there is no advantage in doing more. Spend your efforts on letting them know how you will be a good candidate. If your record is lacking, but you have improved in the last years, you can write about the improvement, of course. But a number is just a number and will be viewed along with a lot of other things.